# CKEditor link dialog removing protocol

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In my CKEditor I  removed the 'linkType' and 'protocol' inputs of the link dialog.

```
   CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
    {
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

        if ( dialogName == 'link' )
        {
            var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
            infoTab.remove( 'linkType' );
            infoTab.remove( 'protocol' );
        }

    });
```

However, evertype I type in something like https://google.com as soon as I type in the 'g' the https:// gets removed.
I checked the output and it always says http:// disregarding the input.

How can I turn this stupid behaviour off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After much research, debugging and tweaking, I've finally managed to pull this off!!!

Here's how I do it:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(e) {
    // NOTE: this is an instance of CKEDITOR.dialog.definitionObject
    var dd = e.data.definition; 

    if (e.data.name === 'link') {
        dd.minHeight = 30;

        // remove the unwanted tabs
        dd.removeContents('advanced');
        dd.removeContents('target');
        dd.removeContents('upload');

        // remove all elements from the 'info' tab
        var tabInfo = dd.getContents('info');
        while (tabInfo.elements.length > 0) {
            tabInfo.remove(tabInfo.elements[0].id);
        }

        // add a simple URL text field
        tabInfo.add({
            type : 'text',
            id : 'urlNew',
            label : 'URL',
            setup : function(data) {
                var value = '';
                if (data.url) {
                    if (data.url.protocol) {
                        value += data.url.protocol;
                    }
                    if (data.url.url) {
                        value += data.url.url;
                    }
                } else if (data.email && data.email.address) {
                    value = 'mailto:' + data.email.address;
                }
                this.setValue(value);
            },
            commit : function(data) {
                data.url = { protocol: '', url: this.getValue() };
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm new in using CKeditor. I wonder where should I put this code?Is it inside the link.js?or just put inside my page?

Comment: @user2699175 Add the code above to the `config.js` that you find in the root of ckeditor.

Comment: +1 Hey thanks man every time I'm asked to modify something ckeditor does I cringe. This answer saved me a ton of research. If could I would give you SO gold.

Comment: @LanceJava Doesn't completely work anymore in the current version, only if the user selected any text :(
Is it possible for you to update this for ckeditor 4.4? Would be great if links were just entered with the URL as text if nothing was selected!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I removed the protocol in v4.5.1:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName === 'link') {
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        infoTab.remove('protocol');

        var url = infoTab.get('url');
        url.onKeyUp = function(){};
        url.setup = function(data) {
            this.allowOnChange = false;
            if (data.url) {
                var value = '';
                if (data.url.protocol) {
                    value += data.url.protocol;
                }
                if (data.url.url) {
                    value += data.url.url;
                }
                this.setValue(value);
            }
            this.allowOnChange = true;
        };
        url.commit = function(data) {
            data.url = { protocol: '', url: this.getValue() };
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's no way to change it. You have to manually edit [a few lines of the code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js#L396-411) to make it working your way.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a way to hide the **Link Type** so you don't have to remove it totally. Set the style to `display: none` like the following:

```
infoTab.get( 'linkType' ).style = 'display: none';
```

I think it works for the **Protocol** as well, but I haven't tested it. I answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025769/ckeditor-remove-link-type-option-but-set-url-as-default-link-type)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

For the lazy people like me, just do a quick core file hack:

1. open plugins/link/dialogs/link.js
2. in the minimized version find `d=/^(http|https|ftp|news):\/\/(?=.)/i.exec(b);`
3. remove `http|https|ftp|`
4. save file, upload it to your server

If it does not work after reload, this might be a cache problem. Open browser in private mode, navigate to your ckeditor and try it again. Good luck.